# Why is this composite primary key being treated as unique, and how do I fix it?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm working on a basic Spring Boot retailer app that tracks products, their manufacturers, and what categories those products belong to. There is a many-to-many relationship between categories and products. When I attempt to save a category into which I have added a new product, even though the combination of (category_id, product_id) is unique, I am getting an error indicating that I am violating a unique primary key constraint. Any ideas on why this is and how to resolve it?

**Category**

```java
@Entity
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="product_categories", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="category_id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="product_id"))
    private Set<Product> products;

    `<rest of class omitted>`
```

**Product**

```java
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private double price;

    @ManyToOne
    private Manufacturer manufacturer;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products")
    private Set<Category> categories;

    '<rest of class omitted>'
```

**DevBootstrap**

```java
    Manufacturer sony = new Manufacturer("Sony");
    manufacturerRepository.save(sony);

    Category console = new Category("Game Console");
    categoryRepository.save(console);

    Category robot = new Category("Robot");
    categoryRepository.save(robot);

    Category electronics = new Category("Electronic Device");
    categoryRepository.save(electronics);

    Product ps4 = new Product("Playstation 4", 300, sony);
    ps4.getCategories().add(electronics);
    ps4.getCategories().add(console);
    productRepository.save(ps4);
    electronics.getProducts().add(ps4);
    console.getProducts().add(ps4);
    categoryRepository.save(electronics);
    categoryRepository.save(console);
    sony.getProducts().add(ps4);
    manufacturerRepository.save(sony);

    Product aibo = new Product("AIBO Robotic Dog", 150, sony);
    aibo.getCategories().add(electronics);
    aibo.getCategories().add(robot);
    productRepository.save(aibo);
    electronics.getProducts().add(aibo);
    robot.getProducts().add(aibo);
    System.out.println("Ids: " + electronics.getId() + ", " + aibo.getId());
    categoryRepository.save(electronics); // <- Error occurs here
    categoryRepository.save(robot);
    sony.getProducts().add(aibo);
    manufacturerRepository.save(sony);
```

**The Error**

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_5 ON PUBLIC.PRODUCT_CATEGORIES(CATEGORY_ID, PRODUCT_ID) VALUES 1"; SQL statement:
insert into product_categories (category_id, product_id) values (?, ?) [23505-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:457) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.index.BaseIndex.getDuplicateKeyException(BaseIndex.java:103) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVSecondaryIndex.checkUnique(MVSecondaryIndex.java:220) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVSecondaryIndex.add(MVSecondaryIndex.java:196) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTable.addRow(MVTable.java:546) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:180) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:132) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:133) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:267) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:200) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:154) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Don't insert the association from both sides. Either add Product to Category, or add Category to Product, but not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code.

1. You use `save` incorrectly. Note that [CrudRepository.save method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-) has a return value, and the doc says:

> Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the entity instance completely.

2. You don’t need to call save on both sides of ManyToMany to persist the relationship. One side is enough.
3. Your relationship management is highly not idiomatic.
   I strongly encourage you to add `addCategory` method to Product which will add entry in both Product.categories and Category.products
4. Better still, re-think your mapping. It is good enough for a toy app, but do you really want to have Category.products collection? When your db grows, fetching this will kill your performance.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Using your advice, I reversed the owner/inverse relationship between Product and Category to make Product the owner, added the addCategory(Category) method to Product that adds the Category to the Product and vice versa, and updated the references when calling save(). It works correctly now.

One thing I'd like to confirm: while I only need to call save on one side of the relationship, it needs to be the owner's side, correct? I tried the other way and it did not work.

Comment: Yes, but with 2 caveats: 1. I would expect the the code to work without explicit save on either side if the method is `@Transactional`, due to dirty-checking mechanism (that's why the method should be `@Transactional`) 2. If it's not `@Transactional` and you want to persist the collection by saving non-owning side, use cascade option on `@ManyToMany`. On top of that, I cannot see why changing the owning side  to product was necessary.

Comment: Understood. 
As far as changing the owning side of the relationship, I'm mystified by why that worked too, but it was the only thing that I tried that resolved the original issue. For some reason, it almost seemed like it was treating category_id in the join table as a unique primary key, even though it was configured, and the database schema showed, that it was using customer_id and product_id as a unique composite primary key. I'm still looking in to why that change seemed to resolve the issue.